# Why does the last line of a multiline Android TextView not display?

Tags: android, textview

**My Problem:** I am unable to get the last line to appear on some of my TextViews which expand to random sizes based upon content. One particular one which this always occurs is the Comment `TextView`.

**What I have tried:** I have read and tried a number of similar posts here and throughout the web but none seem to resolve the issue. A number of solutions include setting **`android:gravity="fill"`** and **`android:baselineAligned="false"`** which have not had an impact and have removed or changed back to a previous value (noted in code below).

Below I have provided the code specific to the comment `TextView` and an image to help understand the layout which it is apart. This is the only `TextView` not to the right of its label and baseline aligned. It seems to be a quite common setup, so I'm not sure why the issue exists.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:background="@color/colorWhite"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:hint="@string/hint_comment"
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:gravity="start|top"
     android:ems="10"
     android:id="@+id/viewComment"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_View_Comment"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

[image: Comment TextView]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change android:layout_height="0dp" to android:layout_height="wrap_content".

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/colorWhite"
 android:padding="5dp"
 android:hint="@string/hint_comment"
 android:textSize="12sp"
 android:gravity="start|top"
 android:ems="10"
 android:id="@+id/viewComment"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_View_Comment"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

Comment: That is so obvious and standard procedure that I could have sworn I tried that before and it didn't work. However, it did! Thanks for your help!